# Adding days, hours and minutes and return the total as year percentage JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I calculate the total of the days, hours and minutes and return as a yearly percentage?

I have the following array:

```
const calculateTime = [
  {
    title: 'a',
    days: 9, 
    hours: 22,
    minutes: 32,
  },
  {
    title: 'b',
    days: 3,
    hours: 14,
    minutes: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'c',
    days: 6,
    hours: 8,
    minutes: 0,
  }
]
```

I'm new to JS, so I'm having difficulties resolving the problem. I tried to convert to milisecons
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what would be the expected output for that particular input? Could you show your code and pinpoint where you have an issue?

Comment: @trincot I was using a for loop iteration but I could not add and convert them at the same time inside the loop. The output is the year percentage for each object value like your solution shows. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert all elements to the smallest unit (minutes in your case), and then divide by the year expressed in the same unit:

```js
const calculateTime = [{title: 'a',days: 9,hours: 22,minutes: 32,},{title: 'b',days: 3,hours: 14,minutes: 0,},{title: 'c',days: 6,hours: 8,minutes: 0,}];

for (let {title, days, hours, minutes} of calculateTime) {
    let fraction = ((days*24 + hours)*60 + minutes) / (365*24*60);
    console.log(title, (fraction * 100).toFixed(2)+"%");
}
```

A few remarks:

- A year can have a leap day. This is not included in this solution, as the actual year is not given.
- Daylight saving time (DST) may make one day having only 23 hours, and another 25. Also this is not taken into account, as DST characteristics depend on the area.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :)

```
// It will do: for each element days + hours + minutes as year percentage
for (let {title, days, hours, minutes} of calculateTime) {
  dayTime = days + hours / 24 + minutes / 3600;
  console.log(dayTime * 100 / 365);
}
```